# Ubuntu 20.04 libnvdia driver packages keep getting kept back

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, proprietary, metapackages

This issue keeps coming up on my Ubuntu 20.04. Almost every time an update is being done Ubuntu boots with low resolution and then I find that the nvidia drivers are being kept back. This is the latest:

```
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.11.0-37-generic
  linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-37
  linux-image-5.11.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-5.11.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-37-generic
  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-37-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-40-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-cfg1-470 libnvidia-compute-470
  libnvidia-compute-470:i386 libnvidia-decode-470
  libnvidia-decode-470:i386 libnvidia-encode-470
  libnvidia-encode-470:i386 libnvidia-extra-470
  libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386
  libnvidia-gl-470 libnvidia-gl-470:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386
  linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-20.04
  nvidia-compute-utils-470 nvidia-driver-470
  nvidia-kernel-common-470
  nvidia-kernel-source-470 nvidia-utils-470
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470
```

Does anybody know how to prevent this from happening again? I am using the Nvidia proprietary drivers  metapackage.

Comment: `sudo apt full-upgrade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade`